# quotes not showing up in report using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html

```
String test = "<span>&quot; TEST &quot;</span>"


HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(test);
```

then i'm sending the following to the report field

```
my.Text = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

So when the report runs it shows

the words the encoded words of the quote you know with the ampersand, is there a way to get the quotes to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
string test = "<span>\" TEST \"</span>";
```

Comment: the test value comes comes from the database, i guesss i can do a replace and insert those